# Entity Framework SQL query throwing a conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this simple query where I want to return a column of a record from a table which can be either 1 or 0. I am trying to use this query but I get a conversion error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Int32'.'

```
public int GetUserValidFlag(int userId)
{
    var query = from r in db.VisUsers
                where r.UserId == userId
                select r.IsValid;
    return Convert.ToInt32(query.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

I do have an instance of db in this class.

Context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VisUser> VisUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried with Find():

```
public int GetUserValidFlag(int userId)
{
    var record = db.VisUsers.Find(userId);
    return Convert.ToInt32(record.IsValid);
}
```

**NOTE**: these two attempts do not reach the return statements, the error occurs before the return.

I am unsure where/why this conversion error is occurring, I can make it work with stored procedure but I would like to understand why this version is failing.

Comment: Can you show your `VisUser` model please. Is this EF code first?

Comment: Two guesses come to mind: 1) `r.IsValid` is null for the particular user you're selecting, or 2) `userId` doesn't exist in `db.VisUsers`, so `r.IsValid` is null. Also, if it's a boolean flag why isn't the method signature `public bool GetUserValidFlag(int userId)`?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` sure looks like a conversion to Int32 to me... why don't you start there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases generally store Boolean flags as Bit fields with values of 1 or 0. EF will map these to entities as Boolean type. Typically in your code you would just use `bool` as the data type for methods and properties for a flag like this. If you do still want to convert it to an Int then you also need to consider whether the DB value was null-able or not:

If the DB value is not null-able:

```
return query.Single() ? 1 : 0;
```

`FirstOrDefault` should only be used with an order-by clause in cases where you expect 0 or many possible results. If you are expecting 1 user with that Id, use `Single`. This will throw an exception if the User ID doesn't match a record, or if more than 1 record was returned. Using the `OrDefault` varieties will gunk things up if a User record was not found. If you want to explicitly check and handle the possibility that no record exists, then use an `OrDefault` method, otherwise it's better to handle it as an exception.

If the DB value for the query is null-able:

```
bool? isValid = query.Single();
return isValid.HasValue && isValid.Value ? 1 : 0;
```

This checks the value and returns 1 if the value is present and True, otherwise it returns 0.